# Finding SLURM node running PSQL server

Tags: linux, postgresql, ssh, slurm

I have the following problem:

I can connect via SSH to a SLURM cluster running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, however every time I connect I get assigned a different login node. From any of the login nodes I can start a PSQL server (installed locally since I do not have sudo rights) which means that any time I restart the PSQL server it will be on a different node. Is it possible to find this node programmatically from other login nodes or compute nodes? For example, if I run `pg_ctl status` from different nodes I get that no server is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more straightforward way with Postgres, but a simple solution would be to save the name of the server on which you started it in a file in your home directory. So for instance, after you just started the server, run

```
hostname > ~/.pgsql_server
```

then in your jobs:

```
psql --host=$(<~/.pgsql_server) ...
```